# Triangle law of vector addition

Tags: vectors, geometry

I've been running my fingers through the internet and books probing why does the triangle law of vector addition works, but I've failed to find a satisfactory answer, rather, any answer at all, for that matter.

Where ever the law is mentioned, they consider finding $R = √(A² + B² + 2AB \cos\theta)$ and $\tan\alpha$ to be the proofs the law, however I am unable to understand why does the law work? Is there a mathematical proof that the third side of the triangle will always actually be the the sum of other two vectors?

Why does the triangle law of vector addition work, at all?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Vectors are introduced in physics in my book.

Comment: Look up the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) from trigonometry and plane geometry.

Comment: @amateurAstro "Applications: The third side of a triangle if one knows two sides and an angle opposite to one of them (one may also use the Pythagorean theorem to do this if it is a right triangle)" says Wikipedia about the law of cosines. What I'm asking is how do I know that the third side is what I am looking for? How do I know if the third side is the resultant.

Comment: Maybe by the definition of [vector addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction).

Comment: @amateurAstro why does everything fit in so perfectly?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/488889/2451

Comment: @user231094 Much of physics relies on math, so even though this is found in a physics book, your question is ultimately a mathematical one. It is not a physics question. A mathematician could answer your question without any knowledge of physics.

Comment: Walk 100 feet east, then 100 feet north, then 141.42 feet southwest. Did you get back to where you started? Vectors are defined to work like displacements in the Newtonian/Euclidean space of everyday experience.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does the triangle law of vector addition work, at all?

The triangle law follows directly from the defining axioms of vectors*. Suppose you have three vectors such that $\vec a + \vec b = \vec c$. Then by the axioms:
$$\vec a + \vec b + (-\vec c) = \vec c + (-\vec c)$$
$$\vec a + \vec b + (-\vec c) =0$$

This means that the three vectors form a closed figure. If a series of line segments has a net displacement of zero that means that the path returns back where it started. Any series of line segments that ends up back where it started is a closed figure.

A closed figure with three sides is a triangle. Hence the resultant of adding two vectors is the third side of the triangle formed by the endpoints of the summed vectors.

*A good review of the axioms of vectors is here: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/121.1.00s/vector_axioms.html Note that this proof uses only the definition of addition, the definition of the inverse, and the axioms of addition.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little about which axion you're talking about and what exactly "means that three vectors form a closed figure."?

Comment: I added a reference for the axioms. I also added some text to hopefully clarify the closed figure part.

Comment: Very elegant proof